# C# / JSON.NET Deserialize Timezone issue

Tags: c#, json, datetime, timezone, json.net

I have a web app and I am using a custom ValueProviderFactory that deserializes all the values for me using JSON.NET, described here: https://json.codeplex.com/discussions/347099, hoping to utilize DateTimeZoneHandling of the JSON.NET library.

The problem is, I have a user on the east coast, but the server is on the west coast.  So for example, when an east coast user selects a time on the website, let's say 09/02/2016 6:00:00-0400 (10AM UTC time).  It comes into the value provider factory as "09/02/2016 10:00:00Z", however, all the different options of the DateTimeZoneHandling (Local, Unspecified, UTC, RoundtripKind), don't work because I get these results:

1. Local converts it to west coast time because that's where the server is (3AM)
2. Unspecified keeps it at 10AM
3. UTC keeps it at 10AM
4. RoundtripKind is also 10AM

Does anyone know how I can keep it at 6AM because that is what the user selected?  Using the default MVC ValueProviderFactory basically gives me the same results, it's either saved as UTC or 3 hours too early.

I'm trying to avoid using DateTimeOffset because all my date fields are of type DateTime.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Take a look at [Choosing Between DateTime, DateTimeOffset, TimeSpan, and TimeZoneInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384267(v=vs.110).aspx).